# Convert XMLGregorianCalendar in GMT to LocalDateTime Pacific time

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert XMLGregorianCalendar which is sent in GMT/UTC format to Java 8 LocalDateTime in America/Los_Angeles timezone with no luck.

Here is what I tried and couldn't get the time converted to Pacific time.

```
//xmlDate is 2017-11-13T00:00:00Z
ZonedDateTime zDateTime = xmlDate.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = zDateTime.toLocalDateTime(); 
//Expected localDateTime is 2017-11-12T16:00. But I only get 2017-11-13T00:00
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`atZone()` does not do what you think it does.  It merely attaches a timezone to a date without preserving the instant in time.  You must do it using `ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant()`, which keeps the instant and modifies the zone:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(2017, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(xc);
    GregorianCalendar gc = xc.toGregorianCalendar();
    System.out.println(gc);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime();
    System.out.println(zdt);
    LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).toLocalDateTime();
    System.out.println(ldt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I figured it out that I should be using `withZoneSameInstant`  after I posted the question.

Comment: This is not working for me. ZonedDateTime utcZoned = xmlGregDate.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));

LocalDateTime localDate = utcZoned.toLocalDateTime;

localDate remains the same as xmlGregDate!

Answer (score -1):

Use DateTimeFormatter pattern to clearly define the date and time format, and with defined zoneId.

```
String xmlDate = "2017-11-13T00:00:00Z";

DateTimeFormatter formatInput =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
DateTimeFormatter formatOutput =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm").withZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));

ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.parse(xmlDate,formatInput);

System.out.println("Output date and time: "+formatOutput.format(zoned));
```

Output date and time: 2017-11-12T16:00

Comment: It’s taking a longer route than you need (should work, though).