# Strange results when converting XMLGregorianCalendar to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, time, localdate, xmlgregoriancalendar

I'm trying to convert an XMLGregorianCalendarObject to LocalDateTime and I'm getting unusual results. **I have already tried the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245272/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-in-gmt-to-localdatetime-pacific-time) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326076/timezone-inconsistencies-on-converting-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-localdatetime).**

I'm making a few assumptions here that I could be wrong about:

1) the xmlDate argument is UTC

2) the return value is PST

```
private LocalDateTime convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate) {

   GregorianCalendar gc = xmlDate.toGregorianCalendar();
   ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime();
   LocalDateTime localDate = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).toLocalDateTime();

   return localDate;
   }
```

The output is exactly the same as the input:

**XMLGregorianCalendar** xmlDate: "2019-09-03T13:22:38.436-07:00"

**LocalDateTime** localDate: "2019-09-03T13:22:38"

Also, this does not work (same method, different syntax):

```
private LocalDateTime convertDate(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate) {
    ZonedDateTime utcZoned = xmlDate.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    LocalDateTime localDate = utcZoned.toLocalDateTime();

    return localDate;
}
```

The result is the same as the first code snippet.

I think my issue is somewhere in the withZoneSameInstant() method. **The strange thing is,** when I feed a different timezone code into the parameter, conversion **does** occur. Try it with "Pacific/Auckland".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd guess that maybe the input is already in `America/LosAngeles`.  How big is the offset if you specify `Pacific/Auckland`?  Is it what you'd expect starting with UTC?

Comment: @JimGarrison thank you for dropping by; I was actually hoping you would see this. It turns out I was querying an object from within my own time zone instead of one from UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first assumption is wrong:

> 1) the xmlDate argument is UTC

The `-07:00` at the end of `2019-09-03T13:22:38.436-07:00` is an offset from UTC. The offset agrees with America/Los_Angeles time zone (Pacific Daylight Time). Java recognizes this, so exactly when you convert to America/Los_Angeles, it doesn’t change the time. When you convert to Pacific/Auckland instead, it does.

I believe that your code is correct.

Comment: Thank you mate. I believe I was receiving the argument object from within my own time zone, so that was the problem.